# Printing biggest even number with multiple scanf

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement, scanf

I would like to get an output of the biggest even number. but when I input `1 2 3` (3 calls to `scanf`) the output is `4`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int ary[100];
    int x, y = 0;
    int amount;
    scanf("%d", &amount);
    fflush(stdin);
    for (x = 1; x <= amount; x++) {
        scanf("%d", &ary[x]);
        if (ary[x] % 2 == 0) {
            if (ary[0] < ary[x]) {
                ary[0] = ary[x];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", ary[0]);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`fflush(stdin)` is UB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979217/7076153)

Comment: In `if(ary[0]<ary[x])` the first element `ary[0]` has an undefined value.

Answer (score 2):

Before the loop initialize `ary[0]` for example the following way (otherwise uninitialized value of `ary[0]` is used in the program)

```
ary[0] = 1;
```

then substitute these if statements

```
    if(ary[x]%2==0)
    {
        if(ary[0]<ary[x])
```

for

```
if( ary[x]%2==0 && ( x == 1 || ary[0]<ary[x] ) )
```

And at last write

```
if ( ary[0] != 1 ) printf("%d",ary[0]);
```

Take into account that this call

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior and should be removed.

In fact there is no need to declare an array. Without the array the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n;
    int max_even = 1;

    printf("How many numbers are you going to enter: ");
    scanf("%u", &n);

    int x;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n && scanf( "%d", &x ) == 1; i++)
    {
        if ((x % 2) == 0 && (max_even == 1 || max_even < x))
        {
            max_even = x;
        }
    }

    if (max_even != 1)
    {
        printf("maximum entered even number is %d\n", max_even);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("None even number was enetered");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
How many numbers are you going to enter: 10
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
maximum entered even number is 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because `ary[0]` is not yet initialized the first time you compare its value to the value read, furthermore it might not be even for the other comparisons.

You should use an indicator telling you whether an even value has been seen.

Here is a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int has_even = 0, max_even = 0, value, amount, x;

    if (scanf("%d", &amount) != 1)
        return 1;
    for (x = 0; x < amount; x++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
            break;
        if (!has_even || value > max) {
            max_even = value;
            has_even = 1;
        }
    }
    if (has_even)
        printf("%d\n", max_even);
    else
        printf("no even value\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
 int ary[100];
 int ary[0 = 0;
 int x, y = 0;
 int amount;
 scanf("%d", &amount);
 fflush(stdin);
 for (x = 1; x <= amount; x++) {
    scanf("%d", &ary[x]);
    if (ary[x] % 2 == 0) {
        if (ary[0] < ary[x]) {
            ary[0] = ary[x];
        }
    }
}
printf("%d", ary[0]);

getchar();
return 0;
```

}